# Ckan Always redirecting to localhost:5000

Tags: python, virtual-machine, ckan, paster, opendata

I have set up a virtual machine(eg., ckan.test.com) and set up CKAN on that machine. Every thing looks fine until i try to submit any form. If i try to submit any form it will automatically redirect to localhost:5000.

Ex: Login page is http://ckan.test.com/user/login. Once i enter credentials and login its redirecting to http://localhost:5000/user/logged_in. If i replace localhost:5000 with ckan.test.com it takes me to the correct home page.

Can any one tell me whats going on

Answer (score 1):

CKAN form submissions now have *absolute* redirect links - i.e. including the host name. The only way that CKAN knows what host it is deployed to is what you put in your ckan config. So in your ckan config (ini) file change the option to:

```
ckan.site_url = http://ckan.test.com
```

instead of `http://127.0.0.1:5000`.

Comment: Yes i did that. But some how it dint work.  I had to install ckan from package and use apache with Nginx to make it work

Comment: And restart apache?