# Urls redirect to localhost:5000 instead of ckan.site_url

Tags: ckan

Similar to this: [Ckan Always redirecting to localhost:5000](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44579033/ckan-always-redirecting-to-localhost5000)

I'm currently running the latest version with docker-compose. ckan.site_url is set to http://example.com:5000, but it still doesn't work.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If you are using docker-compose install the site URL is specified by the docker environment variable CKAN_SITE_URL

This value is populated from the .env file and should have been specified on step 2a of the instructions:
https://docs.ckan.org/en/2.8/maintaining/installing/install-from-docker-compose.html